# Android UI is not showing up again because of glThread in Coco2d-x javascript

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-js

I am trying to incoporate googleIAP using the plugin-x provided by cocos2d-JS , Whenever I try call payForProduct , a popup comes with the vending/billing activity saying to proceed or with some error if setup is wrong.

When I try to come back or cancel the popup it comes back properly for the first time but from next time it doesnt show the popUp if I try to click call payForProduct actually it doesnt call any of the native UI popup. Here's the main class and other util class are similar to sample provided by google for android IAP

```
public class IAPGooglePlay implements InterfaceIAP, PluginListener {

// Debug tag, for logging
static final String TAG = "IAPGooglePlay";

// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;

// The helper object
IabHelper mHelper;

static boolean bDebug = false;
Context mContext;
static InterfaceIAP mAdapter;

protected static void LogE(String msg, Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, msg, e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}

protected static void LogD(String msg) {
    if (bDebug) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
}

public IAPGooglePlay(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mAdapter = this;
}

private Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

private Activity getActivity() {
        return (Activity) mContext;
}

@Override
public void configDeveloperInfo(Hashtable<String, String> cpInfo) {
    LogD("initDeveloperInfo invoked " + cpInfo.toString());
    try {
        //String appId = cpInfo.get("GooglePlayAppId");
        final String appKey = cpInfo.get("GooglePlayAppKey");
        PluginWrapper.runOnMainThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initWithKey(appKey);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogE("Developer info is wrong!", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void payForProduct(Hashtable<String, String> info) {
    LogD("payForProduct invoked " + info.toString());
    if (! networkReachable()) {
        payResult(IAPWrapper.PAYRESULT_FAIL, "Network Unreachable");
        return;
    }

    final Hashtable<String, String> productInfo = info;
    PluginWrapper.runOnMainThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String iapId = productInfo.get("IAPId");
            String iapSecKey = productInfo.get("IAPSecKey");
            try{
                mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), iapId, RC_REQUEST, mPurchaseFinishedListener, iapSecKey);
            }
            catch(IllegalStateException ex){
                LogD("Please retry in a few seconds.");
                mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setDebugMode(boolean debug) {
    //TODO: fix this
    //It's possible setDebug don't work at the first time because init was happening on another thread
    bDebug = debug;
    if (mHelper != null) {
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(debug);
    }
}

@Override
public String getSDKVersion() {
    return "IAPv3Jan2014";
}

private boolean networkReachable() {
    boolean bRet = false;
    try {
        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        bRet = (null == netInfo) ? false : netInfo.isAvailable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogE("Fail to check network status", e);
    }
    LogD("NetWork reachable : " + bRet);
    return bRet;
}

private static void payResult(int ret, String msg) {
    IAPWrapper.onPayResult(mAdapter, ret, msg);
    LogD("GooglePlay result : " + ret + " msg : " + msg);
}

@Override
public String getPluginVersion() {
    return "0.3.0";
}

/* base64EncodedPublicKey should be YOUR APPLICATION'S PUBLIC KEY
 * (that you got from the Google Play developer console). This is not your
 * developer public key, it's the *app-specific* public key.
 *
 * Instead of just storing the entire literal string here embedded in the
 * program,  construct the key at runtime from pieces or
 * use bit manipulation (for example, XOR with some other string) to hide
 * the actual key.  The key itself is not secret information, but we don't
 * want to make it easy for an attacker to replace the public key with one
 * of their own and then fake messages from the server.
 */
public void initWithKey(String base64EncodedPublicKey) {

    // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to verify signatures with
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
    //mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper = new IabHelper(getContext(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

    // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
    // will be called once setup completes.
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                Log.e(TAG,"Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Hooray, IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });

    PluginWrapper.addListener(this);
}



// Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

        // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
        if (mHelper == null) return;

        // Is it a failure?
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

        //start. you can add you own query code here for flushing if you wish

        //end
    }
};

public void refreshPurchases() {
    Log.e(TAG, "TODO implement refreshPurchases");
}

/** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

    /*
     * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct. It will be
     * the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
     *
     * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase and
     * verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will fail in the
     * case where the user purchases an item on one device and then uses your app on
     * a different device, because on the other device you will not have access to the
     * random string you originally generated.
     *
     * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
     *
     * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different between them,
     *    so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to another user.
     *
     * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app wasn't the
     *    one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items purchased by the user on
     *    one device work on other devices owned by the user).
     *
     * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across app
     * installations is recommended.
     */

    return true;
}

// Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
             Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);

            failPurchase(result.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Success!");

            succeedPurchase(result.getMessage());

            //Auto consume the purchase
            mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }
    }
};

// Called when consumption is complete
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase + ", result: " + result);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error while consuming: " + result);
        }
        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
    }
};

void succeedPurchase(String msg) {
    IAPWrapper.onPayResult(mAdapter, IAPWrapper.PAYRESULT_SUCCESS, msg);

}

void failPurchase(String msg) {
    IAPWrapper.onPayResult(mAdapter, IAPWrapper.PAYRESULT_FAIL, msg);
}

// Enables or disables the "please wait" screen.
void setWaitScreen(boolean set) {
    //Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: need to implement setWaitScreen");
    //findViewById(R.id.screen_main).setVisibility(set ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    //findViewById(R.id.screen_wait).setVisibility(set ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}

void alert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    bld.setMessage(message);
    bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    Log.d(TAG, "Showing alert dialog: " + message);
    bld.create().show();
}

//@Override
/**
 * Handle activity result. Call this method from your Activity's
 * onActivityResult callback.
 * @return 
 */
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    LogD("onActivityResult("+requestCode+", "+resultCode+", data)");
    return mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        PluginWrapper.removeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Maybe it is some issue related to activityonResult causing  glthread block from what I think , or maybe IABHelper class new activity is coming up so this cocos2dx activity thread is blocked, I am not sure

How do I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that you have troubles with a ***glThread*** 
I suggest you to try to play around with [hardware acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) at different UI level inside your app (you can disable it selectively at `Application` / `Activity`, `Window` or `View` level).

As a start, you can try do deactivate hardware acceleration for your current activity from the AndroidManifest:

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.your.package.Activity" 
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

If disabling hardware acceleration on the current activty solves the problem, you can try to **identify which view causes the problem** and disable hardware acceleration only for that view:

```
troubleView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Let us know!

Comment: Do you tried to disable hardware acceleration also at `<application>` level?